# How to Install scala parser combinators

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

So, i'm using Scala 2.13.12 on ubuntu, installed via coursier.
Recently i installed via sudo apt-get install the package for parser combinators, but can't import it.

In the official github page, it says to modify a build file, but where can i find it?

Comment: You need to create a new Scala project, it will have a `build.sbt` file where you can specify the dependencies. Please read the Getting Started guide `https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started/index.html`

Comment: I'm not sure what you installed via `apt-get` but as far as I can tell from [their GitHub](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators), `parser-combinators` should be pure Scala, which means it's just a line in your `build.sbt` file.

Comment: Create a new project with a proper `build.sbt`: https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started/sbt-track/getting-started-with-scala-and-sbt-on-the-command-line.html#create-the-project ; Then add the parser combinators dependency: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.13/2.3.0

Comment: Start guide for **sbt**: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-by-example.html or if you would prefer **scala-cli*: https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/

Comment: On the JVM generally — in Java, Scala, and other JVM languages — we don't “install” a library systemwide. Rather, we add the library as a dependency in our project's build. The project might be built with scala-cli, sbt, maven, gradle, or something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very common for Scala projects to be built with a tool called sbt, an alternative to other JVM build tools like Maven and Gradle which is written in Scala and uses Scala as a language to define your build.

As you mentioned, the library itself says to add the dependency to your `build.sbt` [here](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators#adding-an-sbt-dependency).

If you want to follow this approach, you should first install sbt ([here](https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html) are a few options on how to it).

Once you have that installed, here is a very brief example of how to get started:

1. In a new directory, create the file `build.sbt` with the following content

   ```
   scalaVersion := "2.13.12"

   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "2.3.0",
   )
   ```
2. In the same directory, create the directory following the standard structure followed by sbt

   ```
   mkdir -p src/main/scala
   ```
3. Create the file `src/main/scala/SimpleParser.scala` with [the example provided by the library documentation](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators#example):

   ```
   import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

   case class WordFreq(word: String, count: Int) {
     override def toString = s"Word <$word> occurs with frequency $count"
   }

   class SimpleParser extends RegexParsers {
     def word: Parser[String]   = """[a-z]+""".r       ^^ { _.toString }
     def number: Parser[Int]    = """(0|[1-9]\d*)""".r ^^ { _.toInt }
     def freq: Parser[WordFreq] = word ~ number        ^^ { case wd ~ fr => WordFreq(wd,fr) }
   }

   object TestSimpleParser extends SimpleParser {
     def main(args: Array[String]) = {
       parse(freq, "johnny 121") match {
         case Success(matched,_) => println(matched)
         case Failure(msg,_) => println(s"FAILURE: $msg")
         case Error(msg,_) => println(s"ERROR: $msg")
       }
     }
   }
   ```
4. run `sbt run`, at this point you should see Coursier download the library and its dependency, followed by the output of running the command (downloading the dependency will only happen on the first run)

Comment: Thanks, i tried but it doesnt work, it gives me many not found errors with these links: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala:lang/modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.13/2.3.0/scala-parser-combinators_2.13-2.3.0.pom, /home/sam/.ivy2/localorg.scala:lang.modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.13/2.3.0/ivys/ivy.xml

Comment: Notice that you have a `:` in the links you are sharing, where a `-` should be and that just replacing it works: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.13/2.3.0/scala-parser-combinators_2.13-2.3.0.pom Please double check that you wrote `"org.scala-lang.modules"` in your `build.sbt` and not `"org.scala:lang.modules"`.